# Hogan.js renders empty in IE7

Tags: internet-explorer-7, hogan.js

I am using hogan.js compiling on the fly from templates stored in a script tag

```
<script type="text/html" id="template-id">{{hulk}}</script>
```

This works fine everywhere except ie7 where it just renders all the templates blank. I can see hogan is getting the html from inside the script tag but once it comes to `template.render()`, nothing!

Thanks

Comment: I have also tried it with a hidden div rather than in a script tag, just in case, and get the same problem

Comment: Can you edit the question to show how you're calling compile and render?

Comment: No not yet. Please post if you find anything out. I will try and post an example to see if anyone else can see the problem

Comment: It's difficult to give a working (or indeed – not working) example. This fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/wpUKt/3/ is the bones of what I'm doing but it works in ie7. All I can add is that within backbone I get to running `var html = this.template.render( data )` and at that point logging `log( this.template.text )` in ie7 shows me the content of whatever element it is, `<div>` or `<script>`. But the variable `html` is an empty string - therefore my UI is blank! :s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works now with hogan 2.0.0 https://github.com/twitter/hogan.js